# rails database structure idempotent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Possibly not the right use of the word idempotent...but hear me out.

Is it possible for Rails database migrations to change ordering of columns in a database? I'm aware that Rails migrations allow you to have your database up to the final expected state given that you migrate from an initial state but say you're setting up a new machine or something - do you expect to have the same state including column ordering?

EDIT:

This question is less based on something I want to do and more based on predicting change. I have an existing application and I want to predict if I have another user setup on their machine if they will have the exact column ordering that I have on a host machine and if that host machine migrates from state to state that the ordering wont change. Does the ordering on a fresh machine change? It seems that is the case.

Comment: what do you mean, "column ordering"? Physical order of columns in a file on disk? Does it matter?

Comment: Why would you do a data dump without headers? Relying on (implicit) column order tends to not work out so well. The order can be different in different environments if migrations are applied in different orders (when two branches add columns to the same table for example). You're better off explicitly listing the columns in the desired order or reading the columns from the query in question; if you're dumping data then include the column names in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Column ordering is database-dependent, so there's no Rails migration helpers available to re-order your columns. However, depending on your database, you may be able to execute database-specific SQL directly to re-order columns.

I believe this change will be reflected in your `schema.rb` file -- which is intended as the canonical state of your database, and what new instances of your app should be bootstrapping from -- but I wouldn't count on it, as column order doesn't matter to Rails and thus may or may not be preserved as you expect. If you want to be absolutely sure your structure is exactly preserved, switch to using `structure.sql`.

EDIT: To address OP's edit, column ordering is likely to be the same across users on the same database and database version, if they use the exact same steps to bootstrap a database (e.g. `db:migrate:reset` and `db:reset db:migrate` may produce different results). If you use `structure.sql`, both users should be able to use `db:reset db:migrate` and get identical results.

However, keep in mind that database theory refers to rows as "tuples" because things like "order of columns in a table" have absolutely no impact on the logical operation. Certainly don't write any code that depends on a particular column order.